# Css text animation issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, text

The code below is supposed to display "Dedicated People" when scrolling down, for some reason its not working in my browser? did i forgot a reference in the head? When i use codepen it works fine but in any other browser its not displaying anything. Whats the reason behind this, and how do I fix this for chrome browser.

```js
$(function() {
  var text = $(".text");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 10) {
      text.removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      text.addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,700');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 200vh;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
.text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.text.hidden {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.text li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 2em;
}
.text.hidden li.spaced {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.text li.spaced {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.text.hidden li.ghost {
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="text hidden">
  <li>D</li>
  <li class="ghost">e</li>
  <li class="ghost">d</li>
  <li class="ghost">i</li>
  <li class="ghost">c</li>
  <li class="ghost">a</li>
  <li class="ghost">t</li>
  <li class="ghost">e</li>
  <li class="ghost">d</li>
  <li class="spaced">P</li>
  <li class="ghost">e</li>
  <li class="ghost">o</li>
  <li class="ghost">p</li>
  <li class="ghost">l</li>
  <li class="ghost">e</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: It look like you forgot  Jquery script. Do you??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like you forgot `Jquery` script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Here is JSFiddle:**https://jsfiddle.net/8dc7toLn/

```js
$(function() {
  var text = $(".text");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 10) {
      text.removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      text.addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,700');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 200vh;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
.text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.text.hidden {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.text li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 2em;
}
.text.hidden li.spaced {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.text li.spaced {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.text.hidden li.ghost {
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="text hidden">
  <li>D</li>
  <li class="ghost">e</li>
  <li class="ghost">d</li>
  <li class="ghost">i</li>
  <li class="ghost">c</li>
  <li class="ghost">a</li>
  <li class="ghost">t</li>
  <li class="ghost">e</li>
  <li class="ghost">d</li>
  <li class="spaced">P</li>
  <li class="ghost">e</li>
  <li class="ghost">o</li>
  <li class="ghost">p</li>
  <li class="ghost">l</li>
  <li class="ghost">e</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine in my browser. Remember to include jQuery if you have not already.

Go here: https://code.jquery.com/

Get this:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="[insert]"
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

and add it in your document.